# How to clear a masked TextEdit with Delete or BackSpace

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-wpf

I have the following TextEdit, bound to a *nullable field (Value1)*:

```
 <dxe:TextEdit EditValue="{Binding Path=Data.Value1, TargetNullValue={x:Null}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" EditValueType="{x:Type sys:Double}" Mask="##.# miles" />
```

When I hit BackSpace, it shows the remainig mask part (like this: *. miles*), and its EditValue is set to **0** in the background (which is wrong as it is bound to a nullable field)

I intend to make the EditValue to be null when BackSpace or Delete is used.

How can I do it without a converter or a KeyPress event handler?

Answer (score 0):

This is in fact possible, all you need to do is to set **AllowNullInput** to **true**. You may want also to change your mask so that it does not show only the text **. miles** when you delete every value.

Here is my sample:

```
<Grid Background="DimGray">

        <dxe:TextEdit EditValue="{Binding Path=Value, TargetNullValue={x:Null}, 
            Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                      MaskType="Numeric" 
                      EditValueType="{x:Type sys:Double}"
                      AllowNullInput="True"
                      Mask="#0.0 miles"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Did you test it with the latest version of DevEx controls? It doesn't work in my case: when you press backspace or delete, it first shows "0.0 miles", and only clears after you press that key again.

Comment: Yes, that is the same behavior I got. Without AllowInput set to true it is not even possible to clear the textedit after that additional backspace though. If you do not want to use eventhandlers I am afraid it is the only way. See [this](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/6947/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Editors/Common-Features/Masked-Input/Null-Value-Input-in-Masks)

Comment: I think topic starter tried setting `AllowNullInput` to true. The problem seems to be the `EditValueType="{x:Type sys:Double}"` part. Since it's impossible (as far as I know) to put there something like `sys:NullableDouble`, using events does seem to be the only option.

Comment: I do not have enough information to know what the topic starter tried to do or not, I just tested the code provided and it does not allow null entries as he said. And I think the problem is not the x:Type, look [this](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q483355/textedit-not-working-if-masktype-is-set-numeric-and-mask-is-set-to-n-and-editvalue-is). And if he does not want that additional backspace hit or to use Devexpress's provided shortcuts (Ctrl + D, Ctrl + 0), then I agree that events are the only option =)